# How to define SVG gradient in page-global CSS file

Tags: html, css, svg, gradient

On my HTML page, I have some JavaScript code that generates SVG elements and adds them to the HTML page.

At the moment, all of the styling (fill colors etc.) for those SVGs is defined in the *page’s* CSS. This way the SVGs can use the same CSS classes and I need to define the properties only once.

Now I want these SVGs to use linear gradients. However, MDN doesn’t seem to reveal any way to define the linear gradient within the page-global CSS. So my questions are as follows:

- Is there any way to define the linear gradient in the page-global CSS?
- If not, and if I were to define the linear gradient using a `<linearGradient>` element within each SVG, is it OK for them to have the same ID? Will `fill: url(#my-gradient)` correctly access the gradient from the relevant SVG?
- If not, how can I declare a single `<linearGradient>` with an ID outside of any SVG? Is it possible to have a “dummy” SVG that defines only the gradient and the CSS can refer to that gradient by its ID?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there any way to define the linear gradient in the page-global CSS?

No.  You can style some of the `linearGradient` properties with CSS, but you can't define the gradient itself.

> If not, and if I were to define the linear gradient using a  element within each SVG, is it OK for them to have the same ID?

If you mean more than one linearGradient with the same id, then No.  id attributes must be unique.

> If not, how can I declare a single  with an ID outside of any SVG? Is it possible to have a “dummy” SVG that defines only the gradient and the CSS can refer to that gradient by its ID?

You can define a linearGradient in one inline SVG and access it from another.  You can use CSS to assign the gradient.

```css
svg rect {
  fill: url(#mygradient);
}

#mygradient stop.start-color {
  stop-color: red;
}

#mygradient stop.end-color {
  stop-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="mygradient">
      <stop offset="0" class="start-color"/>
      <stop offset="1" class="end-color"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
  <rect width="300" height="150"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: While it's nice that's it's possible to refer to definitions inside other SVG elements, the implementation is quite annoying: if two definitions (defined in different SVG elements) have the same ID, the first (in document order) seems to be used. Even if the last definition is contained in the SVG elements which use it. So a later SVG can be messed up by including another SVG with a colliding definition..